# HttpURLConnection random delay's

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

When I use my UploadHelper I notice a small ~1.1-1.3s delay on random base. So it's not the 2nd request made, it could be the first but also the 4th request.
Sometimes it works flawless without any noticable delay. Seems like the delay appears when c.getInputStream() gets called at: `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));`

Does anybody sees a strange behaviour in my class or perhaps a better solution for this problem? Already tried changing the time-out settings from 10.000ms to 1.000ms, this solved the same problem with bigger delays. The average delay was 3 seconds, when I changed the timeout to 1000, the delay became max. 1.3 seconds.

My class:

```
public class MyUploadHelper {

private static final int timeout = 1000;
private static final String API_SERVER = "http://domain.nl/json/";
private static final String TAG = "MyUploadHelper";

public MyUploadHelper(){

}

public <T> T upload(Class<T> a, String url, Map<String, String> paramMap) throws Exception {

    HttpURLConnection c = null;

    try {
        URL u = new URL(API_SERVER + url);
        c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        // c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        c.setUseCaches(false);
        c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
       // c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        c.setDoOutput(true);

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        for (String key : paramMap.keySet() ) {
            String value = paramMap.get( key );
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, value));
        }

        OutputStream os = c.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(prepareParams(params));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();


        c.connect();

        int status = c.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(TAG, "Server API URL: " + u.toString() + ", ResponseCode:" + String.valueOf(status));
        switch (status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                return gson.fromJson(br, a);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally{
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                c.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private String prepareParams(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}


}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's the cause of your issue but something you can do to help the HTTP client maintain connections is supply the content length of you data. before you open the OutputStream call prepareParams(), convert this to a byte array using utf-8 encoding and then set the content length with the size of the byte array. then send the byte array directly to the output stream without the buffered writer.

Comment: and I'm not sure you need the c.connect() method after the stream writing. writing to the stream will cause it to connect anyway - and maybe remove the disconnect method. iv never used that when using HttpURLConnection

Comment: Hmm tried your suggestion but doesn't seem to improve the delays. Doesn't get worse either.

Comment: is it a problem on the server side? #justsayin

Comment: No, the average responsetime from the server is +/-13ms. Can exclude my server thankgod.

Comment: @SlipperySeal, just a question. Do you recommened using an alternative library for handeling my HTTP requests? And if so, wich one?

Comment: Jakarta commons HttpClient is a commonly used one. i haven't ever had any real show stopping issues with HttpURLConnection though. but its certainly worth trying as an alternative.

Comment: @SlipperySeal, thanks for thinking with me. Just found out alternative libraries have the same problem on 2nd request or later. Starting to wonder how the hell this could happen... very frustrating.

Comment: @SlipperySeal seems like my phone's addblocker was the cause. After deactivating it all works in < 400ms.

Answer (score -1):

try set

```
c.setConnectTimeout(1000);
```

Comment: This answer would be improved by adding a little background and explanation around why this might solve the problem.